# how to store static data that will be localized?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, configuration, relational-database, data-modeling

I am developing a health care system and I want the doctor when starting to type a diagnosis instead of typing it , he can select from a list that will be displayed for him.

the list contains diseases or symptoms that will then be inserted into database in a diagnosis table.

I did that because of two reasons:

- I want all doctors to use the same list of symptoms when writing their diagnosis to work on that data later on, instead of each one typing his own way.
- The data will be localized and translated to different languages when displayed to different regions.

I am facing a problem here, should i put all these in a lookup table in a database or a config file ? given that number of rows are `3000` in `7` languages ( each language will have it's own column ) and i may at anytime add new data or remove.

Comment: I would have thought that the multiple languages would be better in additional columns, not separate rows.

Comment: @cloudsafe yes that what i would do if i store the list of symptoms in a lookup table , i am sorry if you understood it the other way. but i mean is it good to store this in a database or in a config file ?

Comment: @cloudsafe i edited it to be more clear at the top :)

Comment: The volume of data is best suited to a database. Lookup tables have far better performance than configure files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put them in a database.   I find it easier to maintain, and faster to query than a config file.